# Possible to upload an Access 2013 DB to SharePoint 2013 online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, microsoft-access

I have an Access 2013 database I've been working on.  It's not a web app or anything.  Just a normal ol' accdb file.  I'm using Office 365 so I have SharePoint online.  Is it possible to get this database into sharepoint somehow or another?  Instead of recreating it online in my Access App in Sharepoint?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand the question...
What content is in Access DB?
If it's one table and you want to import it on your SharePoint like Custom List, you can save table from Access like Excel and Import it on SharePoint.
If it has several tables what do you want to do on SharePoint: one list, several list or another content?

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't good.  It's hard to explain.  However, over the past week, I've figured out that I needed to create a web app in Access 2013.  From there, I was able import my actual database into the web app, then save it all to SharePoint.  Ok..that's good.  However, it didn't accept the only form I have.  Small database though.  Only 4 tables and one form.  Once I saved it all into SP, the tables were created with no problem (as lists in SP).  But it didn't take the form.  It almost appears like you can't even have an Access form in SP.